# Firebase Cloud Messaging : Request is missing required Authentication Credentials

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, nuxt.js

I'm struggling to get Firebase Cloud Messaging sdk to work with Nuxt JS

I keep getting " An error occurred while retrieving token.  FirebaseError: Messaging: A problem occured while subscribing the user to FCM: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. "

This is my code in the fcm.js which I'm running as a plugin in nuxt.config.js

```
import firebase from "../firebase/init";

firebase
  .messaging()
  .usePublicVapidKey(
    "BDYE2EYHdIp8qHjTKcJYPvO4PgaAH2pSruP55FOtNs5jWsgdeg7YK6OgJ0daSu21kN7aSzU19NRXRqC4bfITZYQ "
  );

firebase
  .messaging()
  .getToken()
  .then((currentToken) => {
    console.log(currentToken);
    if (currentToken) {
      sendTokenToServer(currentToken);
      updateUIForPushEnabled(currentToken);
    } else {
      // Show permission request.
      console.log(
        "No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one."
      );
      // Show permission UI.
      updateUIForPushPermissionRequired();
      setTokenSentToServer(false);
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("An error occurred while retrieving token. ", err);
    showToken("Error retrieving Instance ID token. ", err);
    setTokenSentToServer(false);
  });
```

At the same time, if you are wondering if the user is authenticated. The user is definitely authenticated because I am able to access firestore data and access routes in my pages that I've guarded and I can see the UID details in my vuex store. So that side has no issue. I've also tried removing the usePublicVapidKey() line and it also doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure that the firebase messaging function is called only after the user authentication is done and your store is populated ?

Comment: Tried that already. Same error

Comment: does anything need to be in the firebase-messaging-sw.js for it to work? its currently empty

Comment: you are most probably using a wrong VAPID Key.
go to firebase console -> Project settings -> cloud messaging -> web configuration -> web push certificates & copy the VAPID key. then use it in your app.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem

```
firebase
  .messaging()
  .usePublicVapidKey(
    "BDYE2EYHdIp8qHjTKcJYPvO4PgaAH2pSruP55FOtNs5jWsgdeg7YK6OgJ0daSu21kN7aSzU19NRXRqC4bfITZYQ "
  );
```

In firebase console, theres a copy button that appears beside the key pair. When click on that and pasting....it adds a random space at the end of the key pair.

Comment: Should te random space be removed from the vapidKey that you pass here?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the public key you use is from firebase console, I faced same issue I was using public key from web push package I had installed

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33151293)