# VueJS : Firebase throws error "FirebaseError: Messaging: A problem occurred while subscribing the user to FCM"

Tags: vue.js, firebase-cloud-messaging

The below code receives a Firebase error:
"FirebaseError: Messaging: A problem occurred while subscribing the user to FCM: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential".

It was working 2 months ago (I swear) but I kept it aside to take up some other work and today when I run it again, I see this error. Please let me know what I might be doing wrong. Appreciate your help.

```js
// Initialize Firebase, below snippet copied from Firebase console
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
this.firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "<MY API KEY>",
    authDomain: "<name>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "<URL>",
    projectId: "<ProjectID>",
    storageBucket: "<storage bucket>",
    messagingSenderId: "<sendid>",
    appId: "<appID>"
};

firebase.initializeApp(this.firebaseConfig);

// Call Firebase and get toke, n
firebase.messaging().usePublicVapidKey("<VAPIDKEY>");

firebase.messaging()
    .getToken()
    .then(function (token) {
        TokenElem.innerHTML = "token is : " + token;
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        ErrElem.innerHTML = ErrElem.innerHTML + "; " + err
        console.log("Unable to get permission.", err);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a valid **VAPIDKEY** refer the below link and check if this solves your issue.
[link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62546639/firebase-cloud-messaging-request-is-missing-required-authentication-credential)

I found another article which might help you.
[Link here](https://medium.com/@ThatJenPerson/authenticating-firebase-cloud-messaging-http-v1-api-requests-e9af3e0827b8)

Comment: Yes, I had already checked that link, have specified a valid VAPIDKEY. But no luck. It works in ASP.NET but not in Vue.

Comment: Could you check whether the user is authenticated before using firebase messaging

Comment: Yes, did that as well, using below code. Just to test it, I tried sending a wrong password, it promptly threw error. I am calling the requestPermission and getToken() only within the response of the SignIn methodfirebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("<email>", "<pwd>")
                .then((userCredential) => {
                    console.log('Successfully logged in:' + firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken());
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log("AuthError:" + error.message);
                });;

Comment: I had seen the 2nd link also, that you had pasted but not sure how that will be applicable to my Vue JS project because we are not making the getToken() call through a POST method. It is a simple messaging.getToken() javascript call.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error because I had accidentally generated the key in the wrong project, as I have a few similarly named projects.

So I'd recommend you double check your ProjectID is correct in both config and console URL.
`https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/<ProjectID>/settings/cloudmessaging/web`

Also check your CLI is logged into the right project if you are using any Firebase emulators. That often catches me out when returning to previous projects. I usually write project start/stop shell scripts which check the correct project is active via `firebase use` before booting the dev environment or deploying.